# Python (numpy?) - build transformation matrix from sets of source and destination points

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 2d, transformation

Let's imagine I have two sets points in a 2d Euclidean system:

```
src = [
    [722.6, 1571.4],
    [832, 1466],
    [419, 1482],
    [1005, 2804],
    <snip>
]
dst = [
    [35839.65, 49808.55],
    [42771.08, 41488.07],
    [15764.26, 44065.95],
    [72760.36, 76645.15],
    <snip>
]
```

where `src[0]` is mapped to `dst[0]`, `src[1]` is mapped to `dst[1]`, etc.

Assuming I have enough points to do this (several thousand, actually), how could one use a sample to solve the transformation matrix `M` that results in all `src` coordinates becoming their respective `dst` coordinates?

so `src[0]` in the old system is mapped to `dst[0]`,
`src[1]` is mapped to `dst[1]`,
`src[2]` is mapped to `dst[2]`,
`src[3]` is mapped to `dst[3]`,
and so on.

so for each point pair:

```
dst[i] = M x src[i]
```

Comment: What are the mapping rules?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully this answers your comment?

Comment: Do you need a conversion method to multiply each value in `src` by a fixed value? If so, you can simply use multiplication: `dst = src * M`

Comment: @MechanicPig OP needs to find `M`. `dst` and `src` are given.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for a *rigid registration*, which aligns the point sets allowing rotation and translation, or you may be looking for an *affine registration*, which also allows changes in scale, shear or reflection.

You can use the function [`affine_matrix_from_points()`](https://matthew-brett.github.io/transforms3d/reference/transforms3d._gohlketransforms.html#affine-matrix-from-points) from the [Transforms3d](https://matthew-brett.github.io/transforms3d/index.html) library (although it works in 3D).